# Kendo: inner grid based on passed datafrom main grid does not update model after change

Tags: kendo-ui, dataset, kendo-grid, auto-update

I have following init function for inner grid.

Date are fetched but after the change od some data in inner grid is not diplayed small red arrow signalizing change on the dataSource (model).

So if i processed update request **no changes made** in the inner grid is send back in the request (always it send old data).

How can i solve it please and what i'm doing wrong?

I tried to find some solution here and in documentation but without luck.

Thanks for any help.

```
function detailInit(e) {
      //var dataSource = options.model.get("costCategory");
      console.log(e);
      $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
          data: e.data.milestones,
          schema: {
            model: {
              fields: {
                id: {
                  type: "string"
                },
                estimate: {
                  type: "number",
                  nullable: true,
                  defaultValue: null,
                  editable: true
                },
                actual: { type: "number" }
              }
            },
            data: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
              return response;
            },
          },
          pageSize: 10
        },
        scrollable: false,
        sortable: true,
        editable: "incell",
        columns: [
          { field: "id", width: "70px" },
          { field: "milestoneTemplate.name", title:$translate.instant('MILESTONE_TEMPLATE_NAME'), width: "110px" },
          { field: "estimate", title:$translate.instant('ESTIMATE'), width: "110px" },
          { field: "actual", title:$translate.instant('ACTUAL') },
        ]
      });
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried to set editable as "incell"?

Comment: Yes i tried 

editable:{
          mode: 'incell'
        },

Not working.

Comment: You should set it as editable: "incell"

Comment: Unfortunatelly without luck.

Comment: You should set it editable: "incell" , as I can see,  you add a "id" property for Model.

Comment: Do You think to set editable: incell on model field?

Comment: Fella you should write only like that ====>  editable: "incell" .No mode or anything more.  You should in Grid properties.

Comment: I updated code example in question, could You please provide working example?